# Событие сохранения страницы опций

Tags: php, wordpress, acf

При помощи `acf_add_options_page();` создал страницу опций, подскажите, пожалуйста, как при сохранении данных на этой странице, выполнять определенную php функцию?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
function save_options_page() {
    $screen = get_current_screen();
    if (strpos($screen->id, "acf-options-page") == true) {
    
    }
}
add_action('admin_head', 'save_options_page', 20);
```

"acf-options-page" - slug вашей страницы опций

https://www.advancedcustomfields.com/resources/acf-save_post/

Comment: пробовал, к сожалению, не работает

Comment: Насколько я понял, событие 'acf/save_post' выполняется, когда ACF сохраняет данные произвольного поля в пост, а 'acf_add_options_page()' сохраняет данные в опции, т.е. в таблицу бд "wp-options".

Comment: нет. acf_add_options_page() инициализирует страницу опций в системе, которую потом можно использовать при создание группы полей в условиях. https://www.advancedcustomfields.com/resources/acf_add_options_page/

Comment: обработка сохранения идет по хуку 'acf/save_post'

Comment: Возможно и так, но это не работает(

Comment: Вместо 'acf/save_post' использовал 'admin_head', в остальном ответ правильный.  Исправьте и я отмечу ответ как верный. Спасибо.

Comment: изменил 'acf/save_post' на  'admin_head'